# Is placeholder for the deduced class type of non-type template parameter a C++20 feature?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer, standards, c++20

With the addition of non-type template parameter of class type into the C++20 standard ([P0732R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf)) was introduced the possibility to declare a non-type template parameter using
a placeholder for deduced class type for non-type template parameter [[dcl.type.class.deduct]§2](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4861/dcl.type.class.deduct#2.sentence-1):

> A placeholder for a deduced class type can also be used in the type-specifier-seq in the new-type-id or type-id of a new-expression, as the simple-type-specifier in an explicit type conversion (functional notation), **or as the type-specifier in the parameter-declaration of a template-parameter.**

What is bolded is the addition of [P0732R2](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2018/p0732r2.pdf) to the standard. This allows such code:

```
template <class T>
struct x{
   constexpr x(T){}
};

template <x v>
struct y {};

y <1> b;
```

Code that [compiles with GCC.](https://godbolt.org/z/ansGfo)

I thought about using this feature in new code, but there is 3 reasons that makes me think that actually this feature was intended to be removed from the standard:

- It is not well integrated in the standard, for example, the unchanged standard wording for partial ordering of function templates makes it impossible to partially specialize a class template similar to `y` because the synthesized argument for the template parameter `v` must have a unique invented type (the synthesized argument used during partial ordering of class template specializations) ;
- This syntax for placeholder inside a parameter looks like the "short concept syntax" of the concept-TS. This syntax has been changed to the "adjective syntax" `concept-name auto` after the addition of P0732R2 to the standard;
- On std-discussion, it looked like not all committee members are aware of this feature.

Is placeholder for the deduced class type of non-type template parameter a C++20 feature ?

Comment: Given that you clearly cited the language rule allowing it, what exactly are you looking for as an answer to your question besides "Obviously, yes"?

Comment: Have you considered using [auto for non-type template parameter](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0127r1.html) instead? It is already a part of C++17.

Comment: @Barry "Yes" would surprise me actually. Nobody pointed out that, the way the standard is written, it is impossible to declare partial specialization of `y`?

Comment: @Barry And also the 3 other reasons I listed. But if you answer a yes, it will be sufficient for me to start to consider solutions provided by this feature. Usually I am an early adopter but here, I feel something wrong has happened during the standardization process so that I am wondering if this 13 word clause will not be removed as part of a DR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is placeholder for the deduced class type of non-type template parameter a C++20 feature ?

Yes. [[temp.param]/6](http://eel.is/c++draft/temp.param#6) is quite clear about this:

> A non-type template-parameter shall have one of the following (possibly cv-qualified) types:
>
> - a structural type (see below),
> - a type that contains a placeholder type ([dcl.spec.auto]), or
> - **a placeholder for a deduced class type ([dcl.type.class.deduct]).**

---

As for your concerns.

> It is not well integrated in the standard, for example,  the unchanged standard wording for partial ordering of function templates makes it impossible to partially specialize a class template [...]

Yes, language additions are frequently incomplete and lead to language issues. A more pressing one is the limitation on what kinds of types can be used as non-type template parameters, a limitation that prohibits `std::string`, `std::tuple`, and `std::optional` and the moment. These will be resolved in due time.

> This syntax for placeholder inside a parameter looks like the "short concept syntax" of the concept-TS

This is just what CTAD syntax looks like.

> On std-discussion, it looked like not all committee members are aware of this feature.

So?

Comment: So I doubted: I wrote a mail to notify a hole in the standard about this feature, and the only answer I received, were to tell me this feature was not in the C++20 standard.

Comment: @Barry: "*A more pressing one is the limitation on what kinds of types can be used as non-type template parameters*" That's not really a language issue. It's more of an area where the language could be doing more, but that's separate from an actually issue. An issue being where the language is incomplete: it says that you can do one thing here, but it never says how that works over in the place where it should explain it.